# Javascript Regular Expression String List

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
1)  bla bla bla 

 bla bla bl- 

a bla bla 

 2)  bla bla bl- 

a bla bla bl- 

  a bla bla 


3)  bla bla bl- 

a bla bla bl- 

a bla bla
```

I want to take every list item and put it inside a

```
<p class="bla"></p>
```

html tag. I also want to fuse the words that are broken up into syllables.

I only managed to get the begining of the list item

```
^[ ]+[0-9]+\)
```

and words that end with the minus sign

```
[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ]+\-
```

I wish to do this in JavaScript, but if it can be done in notepad++ too better still.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by a list item

Comment: If you aren't concerned with a complete solution you can do a replace on your numbers with `</p><p class="bla">` and then fix the first and last ones.  You can also combine the syllabled lines in notepad++ by doing a replace for `-\x0d\x0a` (dash and then \r\n effectively) using multiline replace

Comment: for example a list item would be all the characters that begin with 1)  (included) and end at the beginning of 2) (not included) and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to take every list item and put it inside a html tag

I would have recommended a `<li>` tag :-) What you want is the string that begins with `[0-9]+\)`, is preceded by linebreaks or the file begin and is [followed by](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) either linebreaks and the next point, or the file end. This regex should do that:

```
(^|\s*\n\s*)\d+\)([\s\S]+?)(?=\s*$|\s*\n\s*\d+\))
```

Now you can replace it with `$1<p class="bla">$2</p>`. You might want to exclude some of the whitespaces from the matching groups to remove them.

---

> I want to fuse the words that are broken up into syllables.

For that, we can match [a word end](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), followed by the minus sign and linebreaks:

```
\b-\s*\n\s*
```

Then replace that with the empty string.

Comment: I can't get it working. How am I suppose to use $1<p class="bla">$2</p> ?

Comment: In JS: `result = string.replace(/(^|\s*\n\s*)\d+\)([\s\S]+?)(?=\s*$|\s*\n\s*\d+\))/g, '$1<p class="bla">$2</p>');`. I think `$1` and co do reference the groups in Notepad++ as well.

Comment: I was using string.replace(/(^|\s*\n\s*)\d+\)([\s\S]+?)(?=\s*$|\s*\n\s*\d+\))/g, "$1<p class="bla">$2</p>"); and it gave SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. That was the problem. Thanks Bergi